# How to address company arranged temporary accommodation in a very inconvenient location

Tags: human-resources, relocation

I'm moving abroad to work for a foreign company. The company will provide a short/temporary accommodation until I find a rental apartment.

HR department repeatedly asked me which areas I'm considering to look for an apartment in order to arrange a temporary place close to the area and I told them about the areas I'm looking at.

In the end they told me that they found a temporary place. Thing is it's at the **exact opposite** side of the city. It takes 4 hours round trip and costs a lot of money if I go to see an apartment from there. Since probably I'll need to go there multiple times to find a place or set up the apartment, it's a real inconvenience.

How should I tell them (or not) that this is a problem? Maybe they couldn't find any other place but it's a huge city so I'm not sure.

Comment: (Assuming you are not working from home) Is the location that HR selected near your job site? Or is the area you want closer?

Comment: What city are you talking about? I've lived in some big, crowded cities and almost all can be driven across in an hour.

Comment: If HR were responsible, then they will have picked the cheapest accommodation on their list, as it's coming out of their recruitment budget.  Project management won't have been involved.

Comment: My recommendation is for you to find suitable and cheap options, and present them.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I tell my boss about this problem?

The answer is

> Tell your boss about the problem.

There is no magic formula. You contact the company as soon as possible and say:

> You asked me where I wanted a temporary apartment, and you found one on the exact opposite side of the city from what I wanted. This makes it very difficult for me. Can you please find somewhere different?

Are you paying for the apartment? If so then you have the right to decline the apartment they found. Tell them you don't want it. If they are paying for it still ask. Also tell them that the location will mean extra travelling expenses for you, and ask if they will reimburse you.

By the way, it's normal that a company relocating you, especially from overseas, either pays for temporary accommodation or gives you a relocation allowance from which you can pay for it. If it's a fixed relocation allowance then you can still decline the accommodation they found.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm sorry. There must be some misunderstanding. This location would add a commute of 4 hours roundtrip and would add a considerable expense to my daily budget.

Then say nothing else. Just assume it was an innocent mistake.

Now if this wasn't a mistake, they'll tell you, but ideally, you shouldn't escalate this issue until you know for sure it's not a mistake.

Do this as soon as possible. I assume the clock is ticking. Send an email first, so there is a written record of your correction, and then follow up with a phone call within 30 minutes of the email, or within 30 minutes of their opening hours.

Comment: Not clear from question but reading between the lines, the accomodation is not that far from office but far from where the OP wants to go apartment hunting. E.g. work is in central while temp housing is in east while OP wants to find place to live in West. Hence crazy travel involved. If this is case, starts to sound a bit entitled. Looking for apartment is a pain but ultimately a one off thing and just part of moving to a new place

Comment: @plagiarisedwords, Ah yes, you're probably right. I didn't catch that. In that case, my answer is completely incorrect. But I would still ask. May be for something like that, I'd call them over the phone and I'd phrase my request as asking them for a favor. Also, before I'd call them, I would do my research and find an hotel or an AirBnB in the vicinity I'd want to be in. This way, if you do most of the initial research yourself, it's much easier for them to go along with it.